# How to import eosjs-ecc into a react typescript project

Tags: eosjs, react

I created a 'create react app' with typescript and I now want to import and use [eosjs-ecc](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc)

Can I just import it with `yarn add eosjs-ecc` and then do

```
import ecc from 'eosjs-ecc'
```

or do I need to clone the repo then build a browser version with `yarn build_browser`

*(notice the browser section at the bottom of the readme [eosjs-ecc](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc))*

then copy the built file eosjs-ecc.js into the project and then import that built file with...

```
import ecc from './scripts/eosjs-ecc.js'
```

it feels wrong to have to add the js file when all the other file are tsx files. I notice there is no type definitions either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's how you would go about it:

```
import ecc from 'eosjs-ecc'
// or
const ecc = require('eosjs-ecc')

// example
ecc.randomKey().then(privateKey => {
    console.log('Private Key:\t', privateKey) // wif
    console.log('Public Key:\t', ecc.privateToPublic(privateKey)) // EOSkey...
})

// Install with:
yarn add eosjs-ecc
```

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc

An example of LiquidApps using eosjs-ecc in our version of b1's Elemental Battles (http://cardgame1112.dnsregistry1.com/)

```
const ecc = require('eosjs-ecc')
```

https://github.com/liquidapps-io/zeus-sdk/blob/master/boxes/groups/sample/cardgame/frontends/main/src/services/ApiService.js#L3

Comment: so no need to do the `yarn build_browser` ?